# Can I use Aws Cognito authenticate with Twitter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, openid

I want to make a cognito authenticate with twitter.

Now, I'm using below.
- Aws Amplify
- Aws Cognito

Result, I understand below result.
- Aws Cognito only support OpenIDConnect idp provider
- Twitters is unsupport OpenIDConnect(Only use OAuth...)

But...I want to use Aws Cognito Auth with twitter.
Can I do realization?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, AWS has removed first party integration with Twitter because of the ways that Twitter has locked down their auth flow in the past 5 years. You now need some sort of intermediary to bridge between Twitter's legacy OAuth1 flow and Cognito.

You can either write this yourself - make a webapp that completes the Twitter login flow and then interfaces with Cognito to generate a session and token for the linked user. Or you can use a tool like [Auth0](https://auth0.com), whose free tier can both authenticate with Twitter and act as an OpenIDConnect provider for Cognito.